# Proving $\sum^n(1/i^2)\le2$ by induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am having difficulty proving this from a practice problem in my book with no solutions:

[image]

For part a, I set up the inductive hypothesis then I am stuck with the Riemann sum of 1/k^2 + 1/(k+1)^2 <= 2. After that I have no idea where to go. Can anyone walk me through the solutions for (a), (b), (c)? Thanks.

Comment: Notice that you are supposed to fail in question a.

Comment: I know, but I don't even understand why it fails lol...

Comment: Rollback to revision 2. After a question receive a good answer, one should not change the question in any way to make existing answer meaningless. If you have a really good reason to remove this question, please contact the moderators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question $a$ wants you to show why induction fails. Generally when you do induction you use the hypothesis to prove something in general, so lets attempt to do that.

The base case is just $\frac{1}{1^2} = 1 \le 2$, so we know it is satisfied for some $n$.

We are doing the sum
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n + 1} \frac{1}{i^2} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{i^2} + \frac{1}{(n + 1)^2} \leq 2 + \frac{1}{(n + 1)^2}.$$

This fails because we are already stuck at $2$ with our hypothesis. Now notice that $b$ asks you to show the base case for $2 - \frac{1}{n}$. Do you see how this might make the induction work?

Hint:

$$ -\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{(n + 1)^2} = ? $$

For $c$, we can do it by contradiction. Lets assume what we are trying to prove is not valid for some $n$, then show we are wrong.

Obviously there is a set of integers where it fails, so we have

$$ F = \left\{n \in \mathbb{N} | \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{i^2} > 2 \right\}.$$

By the well-ordering principle, $F$ has a smallest element. Let us call this element $f$. We can show the base case for $n = 1,2$, so we know it is satisfied for $1 + \ldots + \frac{1}{(f - 1)^2} \leq 2 - \frac{1}{f - 1}$. But then if we add $\frac{1}{f^2}$ is this still smaller than $2$?

Notice the well-ordering principle is just a way of getting around doing induction in this case.

I don't want to answer the entire problem for you. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks for the input! So from the base cases, it is clear that the sum equals 2 - 1/n, so we can substitute that in for 1/i^2 to have a new expression. I tried to simplify the resulting expression but still to no avail. I don't see what that accomplishes?

edit: sorry I just really suck at discrete math... I've watched videos over and over again but the intuition just doesn't make sense to me. I don't mentally feel the intuition, it just feels like plugging things in.

Comment: @user3367265 No problem at all! I'm just making sure you're thinking through the problem. If we know it is satisfied for some $n$, then we have $$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{i^2} + \frac{1}{(n + 1)^2} \leq 2 - \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{(n + 1)^2} = 2 - \frac{-(n + 1)^2 + n}{n(n + 1)^2}.$$ Notice that this is smaller than 2, because the numerator is negative and the denominator is positive.

Comment: Thanks again Chantry for the detailed reply, it means a lot as I am barely hanging on to a passing grade in this class. Ah I see what you did there, you just rearranged the expression to match 2 - 1/n so we could make some inference about our new expression. But doesn't the numerator become positive since -1 * (-1*(n+1)^2 + n)) is positive is it not as it just becomes (n+1)^2 - n which should be positive no?

Comment: @user3367265 Whoops! Get rid of that outer $-1$. That's a mistake on my part :). It should be $$2 + \frac{-(n + 1)^2 + n}{n(n+1)^2}.$$

Comment: Okay makes more sense, thanks so much! Do you know of any good videos or practice materials to help me get better at induction? Or even better if you know of any tips or goals when trying to prove a problem by induction? The only thing I can think of is just trying to satisfy a condition of the base cases OR show that a similar form exists in some way.

Comment: @user3367265 Practise, practise, practise. On this site alone you can search induction at the top of the page and find countless examples. However, in general, when you use induction you start with the base case so that you know it's true for some $n$. Then you do one of two things. 1) Start with $n + 1$ and see if you can find the expression with just $n$ somewhere so that you can make a substitution. This substitution usually makes the rest of the problem obvious. 2) Start with $n$ and then iterate to $n + 1$ and use what you know from your hypothesis. It takes some creative thinking, but

Comment: @user3367265 you will get it eventually! I would suggest practising some easier examples first and move on from there.